# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in EJB 2.x +Jboss 7

Tags: java

I have developed one small application in EJB 2.x and JBOSS 7.1.1,Session bean related code was deployed and executed on Jboss 7.1.1.final.But,for container managed bean i am getting below exception in Ejb2Servlet.java file at line number 29

> 12:58:09,660 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.client] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)
>   JBoss EJB Client version 1.0.5.Final 12:58:09,687 ERROR [stderr]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   WarWithEJB2/MemberEJB!com.jsebfranck.jboss.ejb2.entity.MemberHome --
>   service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.global.WarWithEJB2."MemberEJB!com.jsebfranck.jboss.ejb2.entity.MemberHome"
>   12:58:09,690 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
>   12:58:09,691 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
>   12:58:09,692 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:123)
>   12:58:09,694 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)
>   12:58:09,695 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>   12:58:09,696 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   com.jsebfranck.jboss.servlet.Ejb2Servlet.doGet(Ejb2Servlet.java:29)
>   12:58:09,697 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>   12:58:09,698 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   12:58:09,699 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   12:58:09,701 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   12:58:09,702 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   12:58:09,703 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   12:58:09,705 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   12:58:09,706 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   12:58:09,708 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   12:58:09,709 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   12:58:09,710 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   12:58:09,711 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   12:58:09,713 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   12:58:09,714 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   12:58:09,715 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>
> 12:58:09,716 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/WarWithEJB2].[Ejb2Servlet]]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Ejb2Servlet
>   threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   WarWithEJB2/MemberEJB!com.jsebfranck.jboss.ejb2.entity.MemberHome --
>   service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.global.WarWithEJB2."MemberEJB!com.jsebfranck.jboss.ejb2.entity.MemberHome"
>     at
>   com.jsebfranck.jboss.servlet.Ejb2Servlet.doGet(Ejb2Servlet.java:34)
>   [classes:]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_06] Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   WarWithEJB2/MemberEJB!com.jsebfranck.jboss.ejb2.entity.MemberHome --
>   service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.global.WarWithEJB2."MemberEJB!com.jsebfranck.jboss.ejb2.entity.MemberHome"
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:123)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_06]     at
>   com.jsebfranck.jboss.servlet.Ejb2Servlet.doGet(Ejb2Servlet.java:29)
>   [classes:]    ... 15 more

Please help me out

Comment: Is your EJB created ?

Comment: Yes,I have created ejb-jar.xml and jbosscmp-jdbc.xml files